# Write apps in pyramid, combine them and reuse their code

Tags: python, plugins, module, pyramid, code-reuse

I am new to pyramid and even though I've read a lot of its documentation (tutorial + documentation), it's still not clear to me how to write modular, reusable code.

To be more specific, let's present an example. Let's say that I want to create a site that handles a forum, a site that handles customers and their orders where people will also be able to participate in a forum, and a site that handles polls. Let's say that when designing these sites, I decided to write the following "modules" (apps, plugins, whatever their name should be): A Users module, a Forum module, a Customers module and a polls module. I'd like to maintain each module separately, and be able use them as follows:

- When creating the Forum site I'd like to use the Forum module and the Users module.
- When creating the Customers site I'd like to use the Users module, the Forum module and the Customers module.
- When creating the Pools site I'd like to use the Users module and the Polls module.

Moreover, the Forums module, the Customers module and the Polls module should depend on the Users module, and their models.py should be referencing the Users module's users-schema (assuming that we are working with relational databases and I we are using sqlalchemy for our ORM representation). Each module should have their own static content, models, forms, etc.

I know that the example I've given could have been solved with different designs, but please, this was the first example that came to my mind that indeed fits my questions, so let's -please- pretend that it is indeed a requirement.

That said: How could I achieve this functionality with pyramid? I think that configuration wise, config.include() is my probable candidate, but the implementation is very unclear to me, so any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

One way to go is to distribute each application as a separate pyramid application using `setuptools` and install with `pip`. For example if you're developing new application that will require `users` and `forum` apps, you could just `pip install my-users==0.1 my-forum==0.5` in your virtualenv and include both apps in your new app config:

```
config.include('my_users')
config.include('my_forum')
```

Both apps should implement an [includeme function](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/narr/advconfig.html#including-configuration-from-external-sources).

Check how other applications provide reusability:
https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_debugtoolbar
https://github.com/ITCase/pyramid_sacrud

Comment: Thanks matino, your answer is enough wrt to the module-part of my question. On the other hand, I am still unsure about how to handle the model dependencies issues, the module dependency issues and the statics. I suppose that the module dependency issue will be resolved with setuptools, the statics (and routes) will be resolved via configuration parameters (include and includeme?), but I don't see how I to write my model to depend on a table from another module's table and how all modules will be using the same database. I assume the latter can be resolved in each module's database config.

Comment: You should store database connection string in the config file and all your models will use the same database. If you use SQLAlchemy which I highly recommend, then the model class name is in fact the SQL table. All the tables will be created in your database, so you will just need to import a model from another package and use it.

Comment: You can use model mixins in a third-party applications, and redefine it in you main project. (for example https://github.com/ergo/ziggurat_foundations)